# Are tuples of tuples allowed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, tuples

I'm currently working on a class with a lot of templates and being able to build tuples of tuples would make it a lot easier

But I tried this simple code in MSVC++ 2010:

```
#include <tuple>

void main() {
     auto x = std::make_tuple(std::make_tuple(5, true));
}
```

And I get a compilation error. The same problem happens if I don't use `std::make_tuple` but directly `std::tuple`'s constructor.

Is it a bug of MSVC or are tuples of tuples not allowed by the standard?

Comment: What is the exact error message that you're getting?

Comment: It's very very long
The initial error is:
c:\logiciels\visual studio 10.0\vc\include\tuple(127): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::tr1::_Nil' to 'bool'

Comment: I suspect Microsoft's tuples implementation is recursive, but since Type0 is already a tuple, it collides with something else

Comment: This also failed on g++ 4.5, but `std::make_tuple(std::make_tuple(5, true), 0);` is ok.

Comment: Your code also compiles in VC++2010, do you think it's forbidden by standard or a bug in both implementations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More data points:

- If we use `std::tr1::tuple` and explicitly state the type instead of using `auto`, then Visual C++ 2008 compiles the code without error.  Trying to compile that same code with Visual C++ 2010 results in the error you are seeing.
- If we use `boost::tuple` an explicitly state the type instead of using `auto`, then Visual C++ 2008 and Visual C++ 2010 both compile the code without error.

It looks like it is probably an implementation bug.

Answer (score 3):

You've making a tuple with only one member --- doesn't that defeat the purpose of tuples?  Anyway, I suspect that's leading to ambiguity.

`make_tuple` combines type inference with a call to the `tuple` constructor.  When the `tuple` constructor is called with a single argument which is also a `tuple`, it's possible that a converting constructor is a better fit than a wrapping constructor.  Hence the problem.

Tuples of tuples are allowed.  1-Tuples might not be.